Cpp Use Python C/API On Windows By VSCode
Can I use g++ on Windows to compile my code? I tried, but it didn't work. I've heard it's because Python doesn't provide MinGW with .a format library files. Of course, that's not my main issue here. I later used MSVC 2022 to compile. I don't want to use Visual Studio, so I used the Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 to compile by myself and successfully generated the executable file (exe). I want to ask if there are any issues with my steps, and what are the standard steps?

First, I wrote a C++ file and a Python file.
I initially tried using g++ (MinGW) to compile, as I am accustomed to using g++.

Set the compilation parameters:D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -Wall -Wextra -g3 -IC:/Users/hanyi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/include -LC:/Users/hanyi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/libs -lpython310 d:\CppUsePython.cpp -o d:\output\CppUsePython.exe
The result is of course not working. Because a lot of undefined references are reported, maybe it's because when MinGW uses Python's .lib file, it needs to ensure that it is compatible with MinGW?
Next, I consider generating a MinGW-compatible library:

Extract .def:
gendef C:/Python/Python310/python310.dll


Generate .a file:
dlltool --dllname C:/Python/Python310/python310.dll --def python310.def --output-lib libpython310.a


Start compiling:
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g3 -IC:/Python/Python310/include -LC:/Python/Python310/libs -lpython310 D:/CppUsePython.cpp -o d:/output/CppUsePython.exe


The result still doesn't work. So give up.





Compile with MSVC (cl) Note, use x64 or x86 (same as python version). Use Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 for x86 and x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 for x64. Run as administrator.My Python is 3.10 x64, so I choose Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 for x64.

Compile
cl /Wall /W4 /I"C:\Python\Python310\include" "D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.cpp" /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Python\Python310\libs" python310.lib /Fe:"D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.exe"


No executable file is output, and many warnings are reported. Four of them are picked out:
warning C4577: noexcept" is used without specifying an exception handling mode; it does not necessarily terminate when an exception occurs. Specify /EHsc
warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Please save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
warning C4820: "":
warning C4514: “PtrToUint”:


Resolve warnings

Add /EHsc
The cpp file originally had too many special characters, just delete them
dont care and solve


Try again

Compile

cl /Wall /W4 /EHsc /I"C:\Python\Python310\include" "D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.cpp" /Fo"D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.obj" /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Python\Python310\libs" python310.lib /Fe:"D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.exe"

After adding /Fo, obj is output, but exe is not output. Strange. Because this instruction is supposed to compile and link, but only obj is generated. If use
            cl /Wall /W4 /EHsc /I"C:\Python\Python310\include" "D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.cpp" /Fo"D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.obj"

 fatal error LNK1104: Unable to open file "python310.lib"


Link

link /out:"D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.exe" "D:\CWithPy\CppUsePy\CppUsePython.obj" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python\Python310\libs" python310.lib

The obj file generated in the first step is used to execute the link command to generate the exe file.




But I want to ask why the cl command is compiled and linked in the third step, but only generates obj. Simple compilation does not work.

you can use mingw but if you do you need to use a mingw build of python

"...Simple compilation does not work...." - GCC / G++ can run both the compiler and linker stages if given the right options.  MSVC has cl to compile and link to link,
